# ¿Por qué al asignar un margen a un div mueve a los demás?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Codigo HTML:

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.menu{
 text-align:right;
 margin-right:18px;
}
.menu a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 10px 0px;
    display: block;
 float:right;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:80%;
}
.menu a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:#bbb;
}
#a1, #a2{
 margin:12px;
}
.centro{
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GOOGLE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
    <a><img src="menu.png"></a>
    <a href="#" id="a1">Im&aacute;genes</a>
      <a href="#" id="a2">Gmail</a>
    </div>
    <div class="centro">
      <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Mi duda es: por qué cuando añado un margen al `div` con clase `.centro`, se mueve también el `div` con clase `.menu` como si fueran un solo bloque? porque no son un bloque, son dos.

Comment: Bienvenido para enteder mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Parte del problema es definir el div con clase .menu como "float". Esto lo vuelve dependiente. Es mejor establecer una jerarquía que vuelva estos objectos independientes. Debajo incluyo el código sin display block, y además con bordes temporales para poder visualizar que está ocurriendo.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.menu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  /*display: block;
  float: right;*/
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 80%;
  border: 1px fuchsia solid;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #bbb;
}

#a1,
#a2 {
  margin: 12px;
}

.centro {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 1px green solid;
}
```

Comment: Para que sea aceptada la respuesta editala y muestra el ejemplo del codigo que tienes en el link

Comment: Hola Gustavo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). Las respuestas deberían estar completas, por favor trae el código a la propia publicación (así si el enlace se rompe, tu respuesta seguirá teniendo sentido). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema viene por la propiedad `float: right`. Lo puedes solucionar creando un `div` entre ambos `div` al cual le puedes aplicar la propiedad `clear: both;` (en este caso he llamado a la clase `.limpiar`).

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.menu{
 text-align:right;
 margin-right:18px;
}

.menu a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 10px 0px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:80%;
}
.menu a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:#bbb;
}
#a1, #a2{
 margin:12px;
}
.centro{
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:100px;
}

img{
  height: 50px;
}

.limpiar{
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GOOGLE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="contenedor">
      <div class="menu">
      <a><img src="http://www.startupsylasapis.es/img/partners/stackoverflowes.png"></a>
      <a href="#" id="a1">Im&aacute;genes</a>
        <a href="#" id="a2">Gmail</a>
      </div>
      <div class="limpiar"></div>
      <div class="centro">
        <img src="http://www.startupsylasapis.es/img/partners/stackoverflowes.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```